# How to get the templates/reports that already created in C#.Net using Devexpress?

Tags: c#, .net, templates, devexpress, xtrareport

Am doing project in C#.Net using `DevExpress` tool. I created some Templates/Reports (**XtraReport**) and I create buttons to display that templates individually from this [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2595).

Now I need to get that all template name and want to show in DropDown and end user select and view the each template individually ??

I can able to get the templates that i created from designer and stored externally from **bin>Debug>UserTemplates** .repx format files and store in dropdown and display in Preview using this code.

```
printBarManager1.PrintControl = printControl1;
XtraReport RptObj = XtraReport.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\UserTemplates\" + CBL_QuoteTempList.EditValue + ".repx", true);

RptObj.CreateDocument();
printControl1.PrintingSystem = RptObj.PrintingSystem;
```

But I need to get the templates that I created ? how to get ? where to get ? Suggest me or help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance. Srihari

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand you have a folder with the *.repx files and you don't know how to make your users select one of the.

You can use this code to load the combo

```
public static void loadCombo(ComboBoxEdit control) 
{
        string path = @"C:\FolderWithRepxFiles\";

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.repx");
        control.Properties.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string item in filePaths)
            control.Properties.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item));
}
```

And then you can print/PrintPreview the report with this

```
public static void PrintPreview(ComboBoxEdit control)
{
      string selection = control.SelectedItem as string;
      string fullPath = @"C:\FolderWithRepxFiles\" + selection + ".repx";
      XtraReport rr = XtraReport.FromFile(fullPath, true);
      ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(rr);
      printTool.ShowRibbonPreview();
      //printTool.Print();
}
```

To customize the save process you must create a custom command handler.
Here is how you do it:

```
XRDesignRibbonForm designForm = new XRDesignRibbonForm();
designForm.OpenReport(Your_Report_Object);
XRDesignPanel panel = designForm.ActiveDesignPanel;
designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.SaveFileAs, DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner.CommandVisibility.None);
designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.SaveAll, CommandVisibility.None);
designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.ShowPreviewTab, CommandVisibility.None);
designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.ShowHTMLViewTab, CommandVisibility.None);
designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.ShowTabbedInterface, CommandVisibility.None);
if (panel != null)
      panel.AddCommandHandler(new SaveCommandHandler(panel));
designForm.ShowDialog();
```

You will need this class

```
 public class SaveCommandHandler : DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner.ICommandHandler
 {
        XRDesignPanel panel;
        string NewPathX = null;

        public SaveCommandHandler(XRDesignPanel panel)
        {
            this.panel = panel;
        }

        void Save()
        {

            //Show a form with a textbox and ask the user to give you a name for the report
            string fileName = "UserSelectedFileName";

            fileName = @"C:\YourDefaultFolder" + fileName + ".repx";

            panel.Report.SaveLayout(fileName);


            panel.ReportState = ReportState.Saved;
        }

        public bool CanHandleCommand(ReportCommand command, ref bool useNextHandler)
        {
            useNextHandler = command != ReportCommand.SaveFile;
            return command == ReportCommand.SaveFile;
        }

        public void HandleCommand(ReportCommand command, object[] args)
        {
            bool handled = false;
            if (!CanHandleCommand(command, ref handled)) return;
            Save();
        }
    }
```

More info about this:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2211
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4354

Is this what you need?

Comment: Hi @George thanks for answering, sad u wrongly understand. If I create `Reports / Templates` from **XtraReports** I dono how it will store (like .repx) and how access it ??

Comment: I told that If i create new `Report / Template` from **Report Designer** it ask user to save the path as .repx file. I can able to access it.

Comment: Do you don't want to let the user select a folder ,correct?You want to specify a default one?

Comment: No sir, actually read that 1st comment, I create a reports from `XtraReport` now i need to get that in dropdown / lookup edit ?

Comment: I don't think i understand...The report you have is an *.repx file. What do you mean get that in a lookupedit?

Comment: Part of the confusion may be that the two of you are using the words "report" and "template" interchangebly, and I don't think they are the same. (I have a similar program where I allow the user to select a .repx template when making a report, and I agree with your way of doing it.)

Comment: @GeorgeVovos Sorry for unclear question. My need is i want to create few reports and i need to get that reports name like "Report 1" "Report 2" and shown in dropdown/lookupedit. End user can able to view all reports in dropdowm/lookupedit and view in that report by clicking it.

Comment: @RenniePet Thanks for your comments, In **DevExpress** tool template is also consider as Report. Can you tell me how u created .repx template and how to use it ?

Comment: @SriHari: Sorry, don't think I can help you. My use of DevExpress Reports does allow the user to select a template (.repx file) and then go on to create a report based on that template, but it is tightly integrated with a huge system, and involves maybe 1000 lines of code. As far as I can see what George Vovos is suggesting is similar to what I did, and is much simpler due to not being integrated with other stuff.

Comment: Actually my real code is a little larger also.This is just to get the idea.If you add my sample to you project will have to apply some fixes.For example in SaveCommandHandler you will have to take into account that the user might click "Save" more than one times so you have to override the previous files.

Comment: Haaa @GeorgeVovos you helping me to create `End User Designer` that i already handle any how Thank you guys @RenniePet for your valuable time. :)